# Value was either too large or too small for an Int16 after many years

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, deployment, iis-7

One of my application is running since 2005. Now it gives error mentioned below.

I don't know what happened. Did any one face any issue like this?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Value was either too large or too small for an Int16.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.Exception: Value was either too large or too small for an Int16.
Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace: 
[Exception: Value was either too large or too small for an Int16.]
   Attach_DL.Generatekey() +121
   Attach_BL.GenerateKey() +12
   Picture.AddAttachments(String _attachpath, String _attachpathDB) +289
   Picture.Btnsave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1416
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927
```

Comment: I can't tell much at all from the stack trace alone (ie, providing the code referenced by the stack trace would be helpful) I'll point out that the maximum size for an Int16 is ``32767`` (positive or negative). Your application, according to the stacktrace, is attempting to put something bigger or smaller than that into an Int16 variable.

Comment: Maybe one the field you are using in your application with datatype Int16 has exceeded value 32767.

Comment: Please post the source code for `Attach_DL.Generatekey()`

Answer (score 1):

suspect that result contains larger value which a `Int16` can't holds. All the type of integer has different range of following storage capacity

```
Int 16 -- (-32768 to +32787)
```

Comment: I am saving same records for many years. There is no field which i give huge big number. Why other data saves as before?

Comment: @MuhammadFahad Primary Key?

Comment: no Bro. Actually my question is that why it is giving error after many years with same data set which we saves before.

Comment: @MuhammadFahad yeah he means the primary key value has probably exceeded 32787, as in you have over that many records now.

Answer (score 0):

Your field might be incremented since 2005 giving now values over 32787.

EF generates your field based on the DB types numeric(5) might give int16, even though it can hold 99999